# PlantUML: need arrow from stop to start

Tags: plantuml

I need the red arrow in figure below. It should go from **stop** of 1st partition to **start** of 2nd partition. So far my tries only got me syntax errors.

[image]

**UPDATE:** the plantuml web site has an example which comes pretty close to my needs:

```
@startuml
start
partition Initialization {
    :read config file;
    :init internal variable;
}
partition Running {
    :wait for user interaction;
    :print information;
}

stop
@enduml
```

[image]

But if I enter "local" start/stop the connection error **vanishes**:

```
@startuml

skin rose

start
partition Initialization {
    start
    :read config file;
    :init internal variable;
    stop
    
}
partition Running {
    start
    :wait for user interaction;
    :print information;
    stop
}

stop
@enduml
```

[image]

Code completion makes this suggestion

[image]

But actually produces

[image]

Comment: show the syntax errors and code so someone can try to fix that problem.

Comment: Posting the PlantUML source is going to make it easier for people to answer.

Comment: Two suggestions: don't use a new start in Main part, but use a connector, e.g. https://plantuml.com/activity-diagram-beta#edf21d7ecb364e82  Otherwise, you can just pass directly from "Action #2 do that" to "Action #3 do real work" since your activity seems to flow right through it anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far. @Fuhrmanator: issue is that I want to produce a digital COPY of an existing written specification. And this spec has exactly this connection in it. If not possible otherwise I have to "deviate" from the original source...